# How to add dictionary lookup option to text selection in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nautilus, customization, text, dictionary, nautilus-actions

I tried to look for some leads to add this option to Ubuntu 22.04 but couldn't find anything.

I found a tutorial that worked on Ubuntu 18.04. But it was only a walk through on how to add a custom option that execute a specified command to the right-click drop-down menu options.

But it wasn't related to dictionary look ups & I can't seem to find it no more. Any information on this topic would be useful.

P.S: Also, `sudo apt install nautilus-actions` repository doesn't seem to be working anymore